# Can not start/shutdown tomcat in command line

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I just install tomcat8.5.9,after I start/shutdown tomcat several times(work fine),it can not satrt/stop.The description is:

```
ceny@master:~/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9$ bin/catalina.sh stop -force
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/ceny/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/conf/catalina.pid
Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )
commands:
  debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
  debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
  jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
  run               Start Catalina in the current window
  run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
  start             Start Catalina in a separate window
  start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end
  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end
  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
  configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result
  version           What version of tomcat are you running?
Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that $CATALINA_PID is defined
```

Then I execute `ps -ef|grep catalina` and `kill -s 9 PID`,the termial will close automatically.But everything is the same except PID----it restart automatically.

What should I do now?

Comment: Look at the last line. What's the content of conf/catalina.pid?

Comment: @fafl   Nothing.I set `export CATALINA_PID= /home/ceny/tools/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/conf/catalina.pid` in `/etc/profile`.BTW,the logs folder is nothing too,and I cannot open 'http://localhost:8080'.It seems that it did not work.

Comment: Does your `CATALINA_PID` file exist and contain a process id?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is configuration,mistake in writing.

The correct answer is adding `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1200m -Xmx1200m -Xss1024K -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"` in **catalina.sh**.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a setenv.sh (linux) or setenv.bat (windows).

In the setenv.sh you can place the environment variables specific to your solution.

For example:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xms1200m -Xmx1200m -Xss1024K -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

When I was running into the issue, I had set up the setenv.sh script, but I mistakenly used set instead of export for my environment variable configuration. In my use case the configuration is misconfigured, which lead to the issue discussed.